# Trying to figure out a regex answer

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to match these items `<script>` or `[cdata]` or `[html` encoding or `<html` encoding. The words can be upper case or lowercase or a combo and I need to be able to find them and keep on finding them. Is my below answer close?  I have no idea what to do with searching for that bracket as it is a part of reg-ex. I am attempting to check with reg-ex 101 and reg-ex hero but both contradict the other and it is difficult to figure out which one is correct.

```
^.*<seescript|[cdata|%28|%3c|.*/i
```

Comment: ^.*<seescript|cdata|%28|%3c|.*/i         ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea what to do with searching for that bracket as it is a part of reg-ex

you escape it using \

so \[ would match [

Comment: Thanks does the rest of it look correct as well for attempting the above.

Comment: I couldn't understand the rest of your question. I would suggest breaking the problem down and finding 1 thing, then when you are able to find that completely for every use case, try finding the next... etc.. until you have found them all.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want, but if it's to find any of the following:

- `<script>`
- `[cdata[`
- `[html`
- `<html`

Use this regex:

```
<script>|\[cdata\[|\[html\b|<html\b
```